# What is the equivalent of apk in iOS?

Tags: ios, apk

What is the equivalent of `apk` in `iOS`?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

They're called `.ipa` files on all iOS devices.

Answer (score 11):

Just adding on but IPA files are programs written for Apple iOS devices such as iPhone, iPod Touch or iPad. Such files are downloaded from the Apple iTunes App Store and can be transferred to an iOS device when it is connected to the computer.