# Why can't handle Android app in ios system?

Tags: java

I created one Android app sorting application in Android sdk
When I was use apk file of Android app in ios system it doesn't installed in it.

Comment: What makes you think it would install?

Comment: Hi, there is a general answer- `Its a different, not compatible platform`, iOs doesnt support apk, in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808451/what-is-the-equivalent-of-apk-in-ios) I found there is a equivalent - `.ipa` files. 
Basically, if you will build apk and transfer to iOS, iOS will "do not understand to the instructions", its like if you will want to run c# project build on win (.exe) on Linux, simply its not possible from the technical logic. For iOs there are different compilers, eg. commonly used for development is IDE xCode, which provides also compiler for iOS

Answer (score 0):

It's normal. iOS and Android are two different operating systems. iOS doesn't "understand" Android apps and Android doesn't "understand" iOS app.

If you have made an application for Android you need to recode it for iOS, using supported langages like Swift or Objective C to make iOS understand your app